# Split a string in Java, based on delimiter, only once, if delimiter appears after given index

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I was looking for a single step process to split a string, *only once*, based on a delimiter, only if the delimiter appears after certain index. 
For eg.

**Input: String--> my-city-hasa-dash, Delimiter--> "-", index --> "3"**

Though the first delimiter appears at 3rd position it is not > index supplied. so the regex should look for next occurrence of delimeter > index and split *only once*.

**Output[]: {"mycity", "hasadash"}**

**Input: String--> m-ycityhasadash, Delimiter--> "-", index --> "3"** 
Index of delimeter is less than the index supplied. So no split needed. 
**Output[]: {"mycityhasadash"}**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 you can use :

```
String[] output = Arrays.asList(
        str.replaceAll("^(.{0,2})-", "$1").split("-", 2))
        .stream()
        .map(x -> x.replace("-", ""))
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Outputs

```
my-city-hasa-dash - [mycity, hasadash]
m-ycityhasadash   - [mycityhasadash]
```

**Details**

- `str.replaceAll("^(.{0,2})-", "$1")` will replace all the `-` before the first three characters
- `.split("-", 2)` split your string two times
- `.map(x -> x.replace("-", ""))` replace all the the `-` in the result outputs
- `.toArray(String[]::new)` collect the result to an array

take a look at :

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-
- [Java - How split(regex, limit) method actually works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47552729/java-how-splitregex-limit-method-actually-works)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [`String::substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) and [`String::indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-) to get it:

```
String str = "my-city-hasa-dash";
String delimiter = "-";
int fromIndex = 3;
int delimiterIndex = str.indexOf(delimiter, fromIndex);
String[] output = delimiterIndex < 0 ? new String[]{str} :
        new String[]{
                str.substring(0, delimiterIndex).replace(delimiter, ""),
                str.substring(delimiterIndex).replace(delimiter, "")
        };
```

**Output:**

> [mycity, hasadash]

Comment: This works as expected, but is again a multi step process, I was looking for a regex which would do everything in one step.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String ... args) {
    String input = "my-city-hasa-dash";

    String[] tokens = splitAfterIndex(input, "-", 2);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));

  }

  public static String[] splitAfterIndex(String str, String delimeter, int index) {
    String[] tokens = str.split(delimeter);

    String first = Arrays.stream(tokens).limit(index).collect(Collectors.joining());
    String second = Arrays.stream(tokens).skip(index).collect(Collectors.joining());

    return new String[] {second.isEmpty() ? first : first , second} ;

  }



}
```

Comment: This works as expected, but is again a multi step process, I was looking for a regex which would do everything in one step.